# PHP7.1 unable to locate package *

Tags: 14.04, apache2, mysql, php, ppa

I had installed PHP 7.1 using below commands

```
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y php7.1
```

After that i am trying to install modules e.g.

> php7.1-soap
>
> php7.1-mysql

etc but it returns an error as below

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-mysql
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-mysql'
```

Comment: May be that your repository only has other versions of php, i.e. 7.2.

Comment: You can check that with `Synaptic`

Comment: I see now that adding the ppa should let you install older versions.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected result, the behavior seems to reproduced only on EOL (End Of Life) release— this assuming you use Ubuntu 14.04 because you tagged it [14.04](/questions/tagged/14.04).

> Released on 17th April, 2014 and has reached its End Of Life (EOL) in April 2019.

Thus ondrej has dropped support for 14.04, meaning you have to either upgrade your Ubuntu or install PHP from source.

I reckon you to Upgrade your Ubuntus immediately, 16.04 is a good choice but there's also 18.04 that supported longer because it is released on 2018.

If you decided to stay with 14.04, then you can compile [PHP from source](https://docs.moodle.org/en/Compiling_PHP_from_source), to find your desired php version visit this [php.net/releases](https://www.php.net/releases/)— this will work most of the time even on old releases.